# Customize DjangoModelPermission

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, permissions

I am new on DRF and trying to allow API access based on groups permissions, i created multiple groups each has its own permission but its not working

### groups

`librarians` `library_users`

### permissions

`librarians` `add/view/change/delete_user - user models`
`library_users` `view/change_user - user models`

#### permissions.py

```
def has_perm(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name__in=['librarians', ]).exists()


class UserPermission(permissions.DjangoModelPermissions):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS or has_perm(request.user)

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj == request.user or has_perm(request.user)
```

### current behavior

- library_user cannot edit/delete their own user view such as localhost/api/library/users/1/

### Expected Behaviour

- librarians members should have create, retrieve, update, destroy, view
- library_user should only have view, change

`views.py`

```
class UserViewSets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API View for User Serializer
    """
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.UserPermission,
                          ]
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, ]
    queryset = models.User.objects.all()
    renderer_classes = [renderers.AdminRenderer, ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would share the way how I solved if others were looking for the same question, 
the below solution would require, the required permissions to be assigned to the user in advance as it depends on `has_perm` condition.

```
#permisions.py 

PERMS_MAP = {
    'GET': 'view_',
    'DELETE': 'delete_',
    'PATCH': 'change_',
    'POST': 'add_',
    'PUT': 'change_'
}

class UserViewPermissions(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        app_label = view.queryset.model._meta.app_label
        model_name = view.queryset.model._meta.model_name

        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            return request.user.is_admin() or request.user.is_superuser
        elif request.method in ('PUT', 'PATCH'):
            return request.user.has_perm(str(app_label+'.'+PERMS_MAP[request.method]+model_name)) or \
                   request.user.is_superuser
        elif request.method == 'DELETE':
            return request.user.has_perm(str(app_label+'.'+PERMS_MAP[request.method]+model_name)) or \
                   request.user.is_superuser
        return False

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.username == request.user.username or \
               request.user.is_admin() or request.user.is_superuser
```

as you can see i am taking an advantage of the `private Meta variables` for queryset in order not to hard code any `app/model` names, in addition to the `has_perm` condition check